# How is the "From" field populated in the Case Feed Email (Answer Customer) Publisher?

Tags: case, email2case, casefeed

We are using Case Feed and Email To Case.  I am trying to figure out what the default value of 'From' is, it seems to be different from Case to Case.

Comment: As a starting point, is the `fromAddresses` attribute defined on [apex:emailPublisher](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.case_feed_dev.meta/case_feed_dev/case_feed_dev_guide_email_publisher.htm)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Our support teams need to send from different email addresses](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000333670&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1): (my emphasis)

> The case feed setting "Specify From Address(es)" allows a default address to be specified for the case feed.  If the department Users are assigned Case records types and page layouts, **then each department may
>   have a different From address**.
>
> For example:
>
> The Users for department A will have;
>   Case Record Type: Team A
>   Page Layout: Team A
>   Team A Case Feed Layout from Address: support@teamAcompany.com
>
> The Users for department B will have;
>   Case Record Type: Team B
>   Page Layout: Team B
>   Team B Case Feed Layout from Address: support@teamBcompany.com

That could certainly explain why users from different departments are getting different default from addresses.

There is also [Email to Case: Default FROM Address when Replying to an Inbound Email Message](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000213688&language=en_US):

> **Description**
>     When Replying to an Inbound Email Message on a Case record, what is the default value that populates in the FROM drop down menu field?
>
> **Resolution**
>   A Salesforce user can specify the sending address of the email in the From drop-down list for email addresses associated with Email-to-Case and Organization Wide Addresses, in addition to the logged in user's email address.
>
> When creating a new outbound Email-to-Case message, the From address is auto-populated with the logged in user's email address. **When replying to an inbound message, the From address is auto-populated with the routing address to which the email was sent**.
>
> If users need to use a specific FROM email address (such as an email-to-case address support@acme.com), they will have to manually select it from the FROM dropdown list as there currently is no setting to specify a default reply-to/FROM email address for all outbound communications.

Comment: As an FYI, getting a 404 on your 1st link. I think this answer may only apply to Classic. My observation is the behavior in terms of the "FromName" can vary. What's in the user's Email Settings isn't respected when it comes to their FromName in Lightning even though it is in the same org in Classic.

Comment: @crmprogdev I've repaired the first link. The old one redirected me to a new knowledge article that seemed to have the same content. I'm not sure on what the situation is with Lightning. It might be worth a new question to address that scenario.